# A la la Lord Raven

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues

> 1. A friend created a shopping center killer whale, thereby confusing the calm pro-llama DEA. (15)
> 2. The tavern string instrument is not available if you're walking sideways like an ole crab. (9)
> 3. After the fifth beer with gas, the spy organization had finally infiltrated the rival agencies around them. (8)
> 4. Hybrid conjunction and Lauren's head salute a licenced landscape architect, mistakenly singing "A la la Lord Raven". (14)
> 5. Returning an original copy to Joe Paul's starting place. (6)

What do we have in common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are all ...

> ... capitals of countries or regions where Catalan is an official language.

Each clue describes the answer in two ways:

> **PALMA DE MALLORCA** — PAL + MADE + MALL + ORCA; (CALM PRO-LLAMA DEA)*
>  **BARCELONA** — BAR + CELO (sounds like cello) + N/A; AN OLE CRAB<
>  **VALENCIA** — V(th) ALE + N + CIA
>  **ANDORRA LA VELLA** — AND/OR + RAL{ph} + AVE + LLA; (A LA LA LORD RAVEN)*
>  **GIRONA** — backwards in AN ORIGinal; GI + RON + A